# iOS Autolayout percentage values

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to align an UIImageView's vertical centerpoint at 40% of total superview's-height off the top.
Is there a way to do that in XCode 6 without any coding?

Comment: There is almost certainly a way to do this through IB, but I am a bit unclear what you are actually attempting to do. Center the image view to 40% of the height, but off the top? So the top of the image view is pinned to the top of the parent view, but the height is 40% of the superview's? Or the height is 40% but the center is pinned to the top of the superview so only 20% is showing?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this in IB. At least not without causing more trouble than it is worth. You can set a constant offset but not a percentage.